# Using arrayformula with dates

Tags: google-sheets

I'm busy testing something out but I can't find a solution. I want to select the name of a person on a certain date. I've managed to find a solution but this requires the formula which works to be manually dragged down for the whole column. I want to have this work with an arrayformula but since index/match doesn't allow arrays I can't find a solution.

Here you can see what I try to do and how I managed now.

[image: photo of the sheet]

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vlookup works fine with dates, but you may need to use to_date to return the result as a date rather than the equivalent number. The issue here is that vlookup only works left-to-right, so you have to reverse the order of columns:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(D2:D4,{B2:B12,A2:A12},2,false))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's no problem vlookup with date, but necessary noted that search key and first column of search range must in the same type:

[image]